# Must the initial state of the Promise accepted by `ExtendableEvent.waitUntil()` be `"pending"`?

Tags: javascript, promise, service-worker

On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache), I saw the [service worker selective caching sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/selective-caching/service-worker.js) quoted from GoogleChrome, then I **adapted** the parameters of `event.waitUntil()` in the `'activate'` event handler in the file `service-worker.js`, and one of the variants throws an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'waitUntil' on 'ExtendableEvent': The event handler is already finished and no extend lifetime promises are outstanding.

*For the sake of brevity*, the conditional judgment and modification operations in the `'activate'` event handler are omitted in the **adapted version**, then the core logic is:

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', event =>
  event.waitUntil(
    /* #0 */ '...'
  )
)
```

The following are four adaptation variants:

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', async event =>
  event.waitUntil(
    /* #1 */ Promise.all(await caches.keys())
  )
)
```

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', event =>
  event.waitUntil(
    /* #2 */ Promise.resolve().then(async () => Promise.all(await caches.keys()))
  )
)
```

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', event =>
  event.waitUntil(
    /* #3 */ async function () { return Promise.all(await caches.keys()) }()
  )
)
```

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', event =>
  event.waitUntil(
    /* #4 */ caches.keys().then(cacheNames => Promise.all(cacheNames))
  )
)
```

**Why does #1 throw `DOMException`?**

Nevertheless, #2~4 are normal. And I can only observe that the initial value of `[[PromiseStatus]]` at #1 is `"resolved"`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you calling `event.waitUntil()` *inside* the listener?

Comment: Of course, and isn't it can *only* be called *inside* the *handler*?

Comment: Yes, it can only be called inside the handler.

Comment: #1 is the only version where the handler itself is `async`.

Comment: I tried it before posting, the asynchronous versions of handlers #2~4 are all normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in #1 you are actually awaiting the call to `cache.keys()` and hence the call to `waitUntil` happens asynchronously on the next microTask, when the handler synchronous portion already executed.
I strongly recommend you remove the `async` from the handler itself.